# Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o visual studio 2012 suporte o windows mobile 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5

Tenho um projeto no **visual studio 2008** para **windows mobile 5.0** e gostaria de migrá-lo para o **visual studio 2012**, porém li que essa nova versão do visual studio não suporta o **windows mobile 5.0**, mas existem poucas informações sobre isso.

Alguém sabe dizer se isso é possível e, caso fosse, como eu faria para que essa migração funcionasse?

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente ainda não é possível.

[Existe um patch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158496.aspx) para windows mobile, porém é só a partir da versão 6.5. O próprio site desaconselha o uso no windows mobile 5.0, por existirem funções necessárias ainda não implementadas nele.

Caso ainda tenha dúvidas, leia [este tópico](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/422a51c9-7990-44fa-b3b4-3719ddeab495/windows-mobile-653-dtk-on-visual-studio-2010?forum=windowsmobiledev) no forum da msdn.
Pra esse tipo de aplicação, infelizmente fique com o VS 2008

Edit: Nem o patch funciona após o **VS 2010**, portanto **realmente** não é possível.